# ¿Como serializar los datos de una tabla HTML y enviarlos mediante Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Buenas tardes colegas, tengo una duda de como podría serializar el contenido de una tabla HTML y posteriormente enviarlo mediante ajax al controlador de mi aplicación en MVC5

Comment: saludos Eduardol, por curiosidad, ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Bueno en realidad lo que hacia anteriormente en mi aplicación mvc era serializar todo el formulario, esto me funcionaba muy bien hasta que me tope con una vista que contenia una tabla la cual necesito almacenar en la BD

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var json="";
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".guardar").on("click",function () {
  $(".trjson").each(function () {
   json ="";
   $(this).find("th").each(function () {
    $this=$(this);
      json+=',"'+$this.attr("class")+'":"'+$this.html()+'"'
   });
   obj=JSON.parse('{'+json.substr(1)+'}');
```

Comment: Yo lo hice de esta manera

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que podrias recorrer los Tr de tu Table obteniendo cada Td y construyes un objeto con ellos.

```
var objeto = [];
$("#mitabla tr").each(function() {
    var tds = $("td", $(this));
    objeto.push({
       column1: tds[0].text(),
       column2: tds[1].text()
    });
});
```

Es un ejemplo muy simple pero es para darte un idea de como podrias hacerlo, intentalo y si necesitas ayuda pega el código que ya tengas y vemos que se puede hacer.